# AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.load not retrieving data from the table in Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to reproduce the example in the iOS SDK guide for DynamoDB. I am able to query the AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElements and AWSDynamoDBAttributeDefinitions as shown in the output below:

```
<AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement: 0x600000038080> {
    attributeName = Id;
    keyType = 1;
}

<AWSDynamoDBAttributeDefinition: 0x600000037ec0> {
    attributeName = Id;
    attributeType = 2;
}
```

But when I try to use dynamoDBObjectMapper.load, I am getting nil values in the result. The table name is ProductCatalog and the class definition is:

```
 import Foundation
 import AWSDynamoDB

 class ProductCatalog: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {
    var Id: NSNumber?
    var PageCount: NSNumber?
    var Title: String?

    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
       return "ProductCatalog"
    }

    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
       return "Id"
    }    
 }
```

The query I am using is:

```
    dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()    
    dynamoDBObjectMapper.load(ProductCatalog.self, hashKey: 101, rangeKey: nil).continueWith(block:
    {(task: AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error as NSError? {

            print ("The request failed with \(error)")
        } else if let resultBook = task.result as? ProductCatalog {
            print("Title:", resultBook.Title)
        }
        return nil
    })
```

The row where Id is 101 is present in the table:

```
{
  "Authors": [
    "Author1"
  ],
  "Dimensions": "8.5 x 11.0 x 0.5",
  "Id": 101,
  "InPublication": true,
  "ISBN": "111-1111111111",
  "PageCount": 500,
  "Price": 2,
  "ProductCategory": "Book",
  "Title": "Winterdance"
}
```

I have been struggling with this for two days now. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It’s fixed now. AWS does not support Swift 4.0 as of now. So once I changed the build settings to use Swift 3.2, it worked just fine.